# C++: Another 'check if pointer is null'

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, null, compare

I know, there are a lot of questions like this. How do I check if a pointer is NULL.
I did research about this here and outside, finding some pretty good answers, but apparently they do not work for me.

I have this structure:

myModule.h

```
class myModule
{
  public:
    myThing *in;
    myThing *out;

    virtual ~myModule() {}
    virtual myModule& bind(myModule &m) = 0;
};
```

myThing.h

```
class myThing
{
  public:
    myThing() {}

    node *get_node() { return &n; }

    signal *get_signal() { return &s; }

  private:
    node n;
    signal s;
};
```

mySubModule.h

```
class mySubModule : public myModule
{
  public:
    virtual ~mySubModule() {}
    virtual myModule& bind(myModule &m)
    {
      // Here comes the 'checkpoint'
      if(!in)
         in = new myThing();
      in.doSomething();
    }
};
```

myObject.h

```
class myObject : public mySubModule
{
  // This is the 'real' object that will call 'bind'
};
```

So when it goes through the 'checkpoint' it's always pointing to something, so it never goes inside that 'if'. I guess it something about the inheritance, because the compiler does not know what `myThing` is or whatever, but it would be really nice to make that 'checkpoint' work. I tried initializing `myThing *in, *out` to `NULL`, but it won't work.

Plus, maybe there is something wrong with the interface `myModule` because of the `virtual` functions. I'm not sure that is correct. Could it be the reason?

If anyone comes up with an idea, it would be awesome.

***EDIT***

I just realized that there was a typo. The 'checkpoint' was wrong, it was `if(!in)` instead of `if(!myThing)`.

My intention with this checkpoint is to check if the object (`myThing *in`) is `NULL`. If it is `NULL`, I would initialize it. If it is not, I would use it.

I have already tried this:

```
class myModule
{
  ...
  myModule()
  {
    in  = NULL;
    out = NULL;
  }
  ...
}
```

But it is not working for me. `if(!in)` or `if(in == NULL)` is returning `false`.

Should I initialize it in the `myObject` constructor? Can't I do it in the parent constructor?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: `if(!myThing)` doesn't actually make any sense. `myThing` is a type.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. `if (!myThing)` is nonsense; `myThing` is a type name not a pointer. You can check the pointers within `myModule &m` with `if (!m.in || !m.out)`, if that's what you want. Note that this doesn't test whether they're valid, just whether they're null. Your class doesn't initialise them, so they'll probably be neither valid nor null unless something else has given them sensible values.

Comment: You're right. That was a typo. @MikeSeymour, I see your point. Yes, I want to know if they are null or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the in, out in the constructor.

Btw, if(!myThing) will not even compile as *myThing* is declared or defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

to check if a pointer is null - just check that the pointer is null if(ptr==NULL) ...

keep in mind that a pointer isn't null at declaration since it will not do a self initialization. so if u really like to check for a NULL pointer u should set it to NULL.

btw:
i would suggest u go one with c++ references, that's much safer at all.
regards

Comment: If you can be sure of C++11 support, `if ( ptr == nullptr )` would be better.  (If not your `if ( ptr == NULL )` is to be preferred.)

Answer (score 0):

As many answered, it is necessary to initialize`myThing` objects to `NULL` in the constructor of `myObject` instead of in the parent. Then, both `if(!in)`  and `if(in == NULL)` work.

Thanks!